# How can I add double quotes to my string to look like json?

Tags: python

I have a string that I need it to convert to a JSON. For example:

```
'{source: s3, aws_access_key_id: REDACTED_AWS_ACCESS_KEY(number), aws_secret_access_key: REDACTED_POSSIBLE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, bucketName: advanced-analytics-mango, region_name: eu-west-1, fileType: zip, typeIngestion: FULL, project: test1, test: False, filePaths: [raw/2017/, raw/Hist/2018/, raw/Hist/2019/], prefixFiles: [X, Y], prefixToTables: {X: Y}, stagingPath: C:/Users/Desktop/zipFiles/}'
```

So basically I need to convert all of that with double quotes for finally can use:

```
json.loads(myStringJson)
```

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? Are you building it yourself or just reading it from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

just parse it using the split function of the string.

```
source_string='{source: s3, aws_access_key_id: REDACTED_AWS_ACCESS_KEY(number), aws_secret_access_key: REDACTED_POSSIBLE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, bucketName: advanced-analytics-mango, region_name: eu-west-1, fileType: zip, typeIngestion: FULL, project: test1, test: False, filePaths: [raw/2017/, raw/Hist/2018/, raw/Hist/2019/], prefixFiles: [X, Y], prefixToTables: {X: Y}, stagingPath: C:/Users/Desktop/zipFiles/}'
values=source_string[1:-1]
```

it is for removing '{}'
so now you just split it into individual key and values.

```
data=values.split(",")
your_json={}
for each data_pair in data:
   val=data_pair.split(": ")
   your_json[val[0]]=val[1]
```

your_json will have a dictionary you can parse as json.
Be careful that what you have used to split doesn't occur inside your individual data.  ": " instead of ":" might resolve some of them, but you have to check the others.

Comment: what if data itself has "," ... it will still split it and throw exception if then ":" is not found. json is a standardized format with rules, what op provides is not.

Comment: Your `values` should be constructed like `source_string[1:-1]`, if you want to ONLY cut off the curly braces.

Comment: This is the close enough approximation I could come up with to convert it to json format. He can be creative and make some checks to avoid those.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda included `'` in the string. My mistake.

Comment: It happens. SO exists to fix mistakes, so we do :)

Comment: as for it failing for values including \, parse it as raw string by writing in the format `r'string'` and test it.

Answer (score 0):

If the string isn't valid JSON, then using json isn't a solution.

If you get the string from somewhere else, consider changing how it is constructed.

A version that would work:

```py
string = '<your string>'
string.strip("{}")
entries = string.split(",")
dictionary = dict(entry.split(":") for entry in entries)
```

However, this will break on many unexpected inputs, especially those which have comma's or colons in there.